# DNN Forum Module Customise to an ID

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I want to Make the DNN Forum Module Specific to an ID. Example I want to Send a ProductID and when the detail of that Product Appears that Product based Forum should also appear. SO How can i do that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for here.  Could you give an example?

Comment: simply i want to make the DNN Forum based comments based on an ID i mean when a user select that ID so the forum regarding that ID will appear not the whole forum!

Comment: Do you want this forum interaction separate from a regular forum? How many different products?

Are you really just looking for "comments" or "reviews" on a product?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are trying to doable with DNN Forum. 
You could try and use Reports module or 3rd party module to query the actual database and show some threads or something.

However, you may be better off just using something like this:

http://www.disqus.com